# replacement function 'operator new' cannot be declared 'inline' [-Werror,-Winline-new-delete]

Tags: c++, clang, inline, new-operator

I got this error when using clang.
Why operator new cannot be declared inline?

```
./test.h:198:1: error: replacement function 'operator new' cannot be declared 'inline' [-Werror,-Winline-new-delete]
__forceinline void *operator new(size_t size) { return malloc(size); }
^
./test.h:18:23: note: expanded from macro '__forceinline'
#define __forceinline inline __attribute__((__always_inline__))

                  ^
```

Comment: Because the Standard says so.

Comment: But why the Standard forbids this?

Answer (score 4):

All uses of the allocation functions in your entire program have to be compatible. Something allocated with `operator new` in one translation unit has to be deallocable with `operator delete` in another TU. Therefore, the program must be given identical implementations everywhere, and replacement of the allocation functions is not a TU-local affair, but a global choice.

So rather than requiring that every TU include the same code (which would defeat the purpose of silent, non-invasive replacement and violation of which would be extremely hard to diagnose), the requirement is instead that the function have extern linkage and not be inline.

Think of the allocation functions as part of the global state of your program.

Answer (score 0):

It was disallowed due to this defect report:

https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue404

The reason was:

> Existing implementations do not permit inline functions as replacement
> memory allocation functions. Providing this functionality would be
> difficult in some cases, and is believed to be of limited value.

So basically the original standard made no preference and as a result implementations chose to not allow it due to difficulty in implementing it, so the standard followed suit and banned it.